# excel how to detect a number

Tags: excel, detection

Let's say I've numbers on `C2` ,`C10` and `C28` on `excel` sheet.

And from `A2` to `A28` I've also got some random numbers.

What i want to do is write specific code or macro(or you name it) to detect whenever excel sees a number in **`Column C`**, go to the **`column A`** without changing the row and take those numbers on **`column A`** until it sees an another number in **`column C`**.

I would like to take standard deviations of these numbers which lies between `A2` and `A10` for instance.
If you can help me to solve this, that would be awsome. Thx advanced..

Comment: You might be able to do this directly with IF and STDDEVA by entering this as an array formula. Can't really tell with the limited info in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the results in column D then try this formula in D2 copied down

`=IF(ISNUMBER(C2),STDEV(A2:INDEX(A3:A$1000,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(C3:C$1000),0),0)-1)),"")`

That will work for up to 1000 rows of data (adjust as required) giving the STDEV of the range of numbers from the current row (for each cell in col C with a number) to the row before the next number, e.g. for your example D2 will give you `=STDEV(A2:A9)` because A10 will be included in the D10 value

Comment: First of all thx! It's almost what i need...And let me be more specific about it. What I exactly need is: Lets say I've a number at C10 and C20. And bunch of numbers lies between them on the colA(include A10 and A20). A11 is going to be my first number and A20 is last number. Plus (row20 - row10) = 10. So, finally  ( A11,.....A20 + (row20-row10) ) and i want these numbers standardDev and i would like to print this to D20. And so on for the rest of the list..